# handlebars.js renders blank rows for empty array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

js, every thing works nicely except when an array is empty. I tried using if else but handlebars still render a blank row if array is empty.

```
{{#each invoice_id.invoice_services}}                       
    <tr class="uk-table-middle">
        <td>
            <span class="uk-text-large">{{ service_name }}</span><br/>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">{{ service_description }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ service_rate }}
        </td>
        <td class="uk-text-center">
            {{ service_hours }}
        </td>
        <td class="uk-text-center">
            {{ service_vat }}
        </td>
        <td class="uk-text-center">
           {{ service_total }}
        </td>
    </tr>                                                 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That shouldnt be the case. Check invoice_id.invoice_services.length.

Comment: tried using {{#each invoice_id.invoice_services.length}} and {{#if invoice_id.invoice_services.length}} still not working

Comment: My guess is that you must have initialized invoice_id.invoice_services as an array with one empty object. Just use `{{invoice_id.invoice_services.length}}` somewhere and check what is the value shown.

Comment: Is this Handlebars or Ember.js? `{{#each array}}` isn't allowed in Ember.js, you have to do `{{#each array as |item|}}`.